# How to make transparent UIButton in UITableView Cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When My .Xib File Is Loaded That Time `UITableViewCell` is Fill Up With Black Background Color,For That, I am using

```
cell.contentView.backGroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]
```

But In `UITableViewCell` One `UIButton` With "Custom" Button Type Is Generated Programatically
so the area Cover By `UIButton` is a Not `transparent` (Or Cell background - black Color is Not Display), it is a white color,,,

I Want To Make `UIButton` With Transparent Background

SO How I Can ?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIButton *button;
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: You need to change your button type to custom first. @prithvi

Answer (score 1):

```
try this one it work for me
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(aMethod:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 5.0, 160.0, 40.0);
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make an image of button along with text you want to show and add this as button background with button type custom.